# Jquery Validation with Identical Form Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that does 2 things:

1. Pass a first name and email address to PHP.
2. Dynamically add a new set of name/email fields on a click, in case the user wants to submit more than one or two sets of data.

Since I don't know exactly how many sets every user may choose to submit, I pass the data to PHP in an array (using a name followed by []), so I can use a foreach loop and always get every data set. Here is some code for better understanding:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" id="formID">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="contacts">
<tr>
    <td><label class="namelabel"><span>Friend's First Name:</span><input type="text" name="friendName[]" class="friendName" id="name1" /></label></td>
    <td><label class="emaillabel"><span>Friend's Email:</span><input type="text" name="friendEmail[]" class="friendEmail" id="email1" /></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="addmore"><a href="#" id="addclick">Click Here To Send This To More Friends</a></p>
<input type="submit" value="Spread The News!" name="submit" />
    </form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.validate.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        fieldCount = 1;
        $("#addclick").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            fieldCount+=1;
            $('#contacts tr:last').after('<tr><td><label class="namelabel"><span>Friend\'s First Name:</span><input type="text" name="friendName[]" class="friendName" id="name' + fieldCount + '" /></label></td><td><label class="emaillabel"><span>Friend\'s Email:</span><input type="text" name="friendEmail[]" class="friendEmail" id="email' + fieldCount + '" /></label></td></tr>');
        });
        $("#formID").validate({
rules: {
    "friendName[]": "required",
    "friendEmail[]": "required email",
  }
});
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is, however, that only the first friendName[] and friendEmail[] get validated on submission. You have to click on any other fields with the same name to get validation working (Like the lazy validation only kicks in after focus)

How can I use the same name for a form field, and get all of them validated at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps.

1) Open jquery.validate.js file
2) Find checkForm: function() {
3) Replace this function with below code.

```
checkForm: function() {
    this.prepareForm();
    for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
        if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
            for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                    this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
            }
        } else {
            this.check( elements[i] );
        }
    }
    return this.valid();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because each dynamically added item needs a unique name, check out this post on SO about this exact problem.

[Using JQuery Validate Plugin to validate multiple form fields with identical names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931687/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-validate-multiple-form-fields-with-identical-name)

Comment: I can give each element a unique name (in fact, I've given each element a unique ID with the code above), but that negates the usefulness of using something like friendName[] for a name and passing an array of values to PHP.

I wanted to pass an array to cut down on the logic needed on the backend, so I don't have to account for each and every possible number of data sets (or set a hard limit on the number) - I can just loop through $_POST['friendName'] with a foreach.

Comment: If you have a better way to handle an indefinite number of name and email data sets in PHP, each with a unique name, I'm all ears, though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit shaky on JQuery idiom. However adding this callback to the validate call works:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  var els = $('.friendName, .friendEmail');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    $(form).validate().element(els[i]);
  }
}
```

Obviously someone who knew JQuery idiom (aka hlep1!) could remove the assign to `els` and the loop.

The submit handler is only called once the form is valid. The form is valid once the first instance of each name is checked. An alternative would be to hack/monkeypatch your plugin to remove that check.

Comment: `els.each(function() { $(form).validate().element(this); });`