# Using jquery validate with multiple fields of the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get jquery validate to work on multiple fields.  Reason being I have dynamically generated fields added and they are simply a list of phone numbers from none to as many as required.  A button adds another number.

So I thought I'd put together a basic example and followed the concept from the accepted answer in the following link:

[Using JQuery Validate Plugin to validate multiple form fields with identical names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931687/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-validate-multiple-form-fields-with-identical-name)

However, it's not doing anything useful.  Why is it not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/lib/jquery.delegate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<script>
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $("field").each(function(){
      $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        messages: {
          required: "Specify a valid email"
        }
      });   
    })
  });


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate();
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="myform">
  <label for="field">Required, email: </label>
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This: `$("field").each(function(){`
Should be: `$("[name=field]").each(function(){`

Also your IDs should be unique, you'll get unpredictable behavior when this isn't true.  Also, you should move the rule adding inside the `document.ready`, like this (this is now all your script):

```
$(function(){
  $("#myform").validate();
  $("[name=field]").each(function(){
     $(this).rules("add", {
       required: true,
       email: true,
       messages: {
         required: "Specify a valid email"
       }
     });   
   });
});
```

Comment: your solution just worked for me to select inputs in this way: $("[name^=foo][name$=bar]").each(function(). That would select the inputs whose name attribute starts with "foo" AND end with "bar", for example "foo_bar", but it doesn't work with "foobar"...:)

Comment: @user248959 - It should work fine for `name="foobar"` as well (since it meets the criteria), you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fM52H/

Comment: @NickCraver , but it validates my first textbox only

Comment: @PratikJoshi do you have the textboxes in individual forms, all with the same ID? That would have this behavior, but is not valid HTML - IDs should be unique.

Comment: For this structure i tried , but did not work => <input type="text" name="videoTag[]">

Comment: I added This code but only first one (txtbox) gets validated =>   jQuery("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
  //For custom Validation
  jQuery('input[name="videoTag[]"]').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).rules("add", {
    required: true,   
    messages: {
    required: "Add video URL"
    }
   }); 
   //alert("counter");
  });
  //For Custom validation  
  jQuery("#frmAddPlaylist").validate();
 });
 // validate the comment form when it is submitted

Comment: @PratikJoshi the rules shouldn't be added inside the click handler, they should be there when the form anytime after the form elements are created/available. You should post a new question with the source of all your forms/fields along with that JavaScript - I can't see the structure from your comment, which is likely the actual issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508638/jquery-validate-for-multiple-fields-having-same-name

Comment: Your answer is wrong . There is NO Solution . See What Sprky(Gold medal in jQuery-Validate) said "You cannot have multiple fields sharing the same name".  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508638/jquery-validate-for-multiple-fields-having-same-name?noredirect=1#comment37953232_24508638

Comment: @PratikJoshi, actually, this answer shows a valid way to assign rules to multiple fields at once.  However, since the selector, `$("[name=field]")`, is targeting a single `name`, it's technically incorrect.  If the selector was tweaked, this answer would be 100% correct.  However, everyone keep in mind that no matter how rules are assigned to fields, every field MUST contain a _unique_ `name` as that's how this plugin keeps track of each input.

Comment: @PratikJoshi, See [this broken jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3gz/) which demonstrates that you cannot have the same `name` on multiple fields.  Now look at this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D49MD/) where all fields have a unique `name`.  Same technique from this answer is used in both.

Comment: What to do if all field should share common error message instead of individual?

Comment: its targeting the first one only there is no solution with each function..only solution is if you change the function in jquery.vaidate.js file

Answer (score 0):

@pratik
[JqueryValidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org) maintaining rulesCache, You need to modify core library.

```
elements: function() {
    var validator = this,
        rulesCache = {};

    // select all valid inputs inside the form (no submit or reset buttons)
    return $(this.currentForm)
        .find("input, select, textarea")
        .not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")
        .not(this.settings.ignore)
        .filter(function() {
            if (!this.name && validator.settings.debug && window.console) {
                console.error("%o has no name assigned", this);
            }

            // select only the first element for each name, and only those with rules specified
            if (this.name in rulesCache || !validator.objectLength($(this).rules())) {
                return false;
            }

            rulesCache[this.name] = true;
            return true;
        });
},
```

Just comment the rulesCache[this.name] = true;

```
elements: function() {
    var validator = this,
        rulesCache = {};

    // select all valid inputs inside the form (no submit or reset buttons)
    return $(this.currentForm)
        .find("input, select, textarea")
        .not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")
        .not(this.settings.ignore)
        .filter(function() {
            if (!this.name && validator.settings.debug && window.console) {
                console.error("%o has no name assigned", this);
            }

            // select only the first element for each name, and only those with rules specified
            if (this.name in rulesCache || !validator.objectLength($(this).rules())) {
                return false;
            }

            // rulesCache[this.name] = true;
            return true;
        });
},
```

If you don't want to change in core library file. there is another solution. Just override existing core function.

```
$.validator.prototype.checkForm = function (){
  this.prepareForm();
    for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
        if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
            for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
            }
        } 
        else {
            this.check( elements[i] );
        }
    }
    return this.valid();
};
```