# Match two fields with jQuery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I have an e-mail field, and a confirm e-mail field. I need to validate both of them to make sure their values match.

Is there a way to add a rule to match those two fields?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931687/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-validate-multiple-form-fields-with-identical-name

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could use the [equalTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo) method:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        email: 'required',
        emailConfirm: {
            equalTo: '#email'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you tell how to add custom message for this?

Comment: Sure, use the `messages` attribute. I strongly suggest you to reading the documentation of the jquery validate plugin which contains all the necessary details: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: @sreemanthpulagam Yep, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777634/jquery-validation-plugin-custom-message

Comment: How to multiple for single input fields ?

Answer (score 24):

You can also do this on the second field:

```
 class="required email" equalTo='#email'
```

Comment: Does this need hte Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

> U can use this

```
email: {
      required: true, email: true
      },
c_email: { 
                required: true, equalTo: "#email", minlength: 5
          },

<div class="form-row"><span class="label">email</span><input type="email" name="email" class="required" id="email" /></div>

<div class="form-row"><span class="label">Confirm email</span><input type="email" name="c_email" id="c_email" /></div>
```