# jQuery Validation plugin - Custom message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am new to JQuery and am using the [JQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

I would like to ask, how to override the default messages to display also text in label associated with form element.

I would get message something like this:

**Field Password is required.** instead of default *This field is required*.

**Field PostCode must contain at least 3 characters.** instead of default *Please enter at least 3 characters.*

I need to override the default behaviour of this plugin, because I do not want to specify custom message for each item for every type of validation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 48):

```
$("#signupform")
    .validate({
        rules: {
            password: "required",
            postcode: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: "Field Password is required",
            postcode: {
                required: "Field PostCode is required",
                minlength: "Field PostCode must contain at least 3 characters" 
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as i said:
I need to override the default behaviour of this plugin, because I do not want to specify custom message for each item for every type of validation.

Your answer is exactly what I do not want.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, missed that bit. Well, the only way I can see for you to overwrite the default messages, is by editing the plugin, which I wouldn't recommend. See if [`invalidHandler`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) will work for you, otherwise the options seem limited here.

Comment: also it's possible to set special messages for special inputs by this way: `data-msg-required="Please enter your email address"` or  `data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address"` in html markup.

Answer (score 18):

This is what I found when I was looking for the same thing a couple of days ago. Unfortunately I can't remember where I found it, so I can't give the person who wrote the answer credit.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required:"This field is required.",
    equalTo:"Password fields do not match.",
    email:"Please enter a valid email.",
});
```

Answer (score 10):

There's a more concise way to achieve this.

> Use "**data-msg**" or "**data-msg-**(rulename)" to override default error message for a predefined rule or a custom rule. (after jQuery validation v1.11.0, currently v1.16.0)

```
<input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" value=""
       required
       data-msg-required="Field Password is required." />

<input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" value=""
       required
       data-msg-required="Field PostCode is required."
       minlength="3"
       data-msg-minlength="Field PostCode must contain at least 3 characters." />
```

Comment: Best answer so far if you need to customize only one or two error messages!

Comment: Thanks! This helped me when I was dynamically creating input fields with dynamic names.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do the same thing, and ended up creating a custom method so that its message could be shared across multiple forms.

I found this answer in a similar Stack Overflow question: [How can we specify rules for jquery validation plugin by class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461571/how-can-we-specify-rules-for-jquery-validation-plugin-by-class)

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "newEmail", //name of a virtual validator
    $.validator.methods.email, //use the actual email validator
    "Custom error message"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

add this after the plugin:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "Your new default message",
    email: "That's not a valid email"
});
```

you can put it in a separate file if you want, but make sure it's included after the plugin itself