# Setting same properties for more fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have two or more text fields and I want to apply the same properties to them, avoiding to write two or more times the same code

This doesn't work:

```
$("#form").validate({  
    rules:  
    {
    'name', 'surname':{  
        required: true,  
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50   
        }
    }
});
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
var ruleSet1 = {
        required: true,  
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50
    };

$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: ruleSet1,
        field_2: ruleSet1,
        field_3: ruleSet1
    }
});
```

or do it one by one like the following,

```
$("#form").validate({  
    rules:  
    {
    name: { required: true },
    surname:{  
        required: true,  
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50   
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all!! And if I would add a single property only to field_1 holding the ruleSet1?

Comment: [This answer looks really familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9461732/594235)... @FredKafka, you'd need to use jQuery `extend()` to modify the set.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

apply a css class to all fields

```
$(".cssClassName").rules("add", {
        required: true,  
         minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 50 ,
        messages:
   {required:"error1",minlength:"error2",maxlength:"error3"}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your properties as a variable, and then use it:

```
var name_reqs = {  
     required: true,  
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 50   
};

$("#form").validate({  
    rules: {
           'name': name_reqs,
        'surname': name_reqs
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there are a few ways to do this but if you use a [**class rule:**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#namerules)

```
$.validator.addClassRules("name", {
  required: true,  
  minlength: 3,
  maxlength: 50
});
```

then you can set your rules like so

```
$("#form").validate({  
    rules:  
    {
     firstname : name, 
     surname : name
    }
});
```

or set the rule using class name:

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" class="name">
<input id="surname" name="surnname" class="name">
```

This method is discussed in the [refactoring rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Refactoring_rules) section of the jQuery validate general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461732/594235):

---

For the purposes of my example, this is the base starting code:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="field_1" />
<input type="text" name="field_2" />
<input type="text" name="field_3" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        field_2: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        field_3: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/

---

**Option 1a)**  You can assign classes to your fields based on desired common rules and then assign those rules to the classes.  You can also assign custom messages.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="field_1" class="num" />
<input type="text" name="field_2" class="num" />
<input type="text" name="field_3" class="num" />
```

The [`.rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) **must** be called *after* invoking `.validate()` and `.each()` must be used to target all elements with the `class`.

jQuery:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    // your other plugin options
});

$('.num').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        messages: {
            required:  "your custom message",
            number:  "your custom message"
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/1/

**Option 1b)**  Same as above, but instead of using a `class`, it matches a common part of the name attribute:

```
$('[name*="field"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        messages: { // optional custom messages
            required:  "your custom message",
            number:  "your custom message"
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/6/

---

**Option 2a)**  You can pull out the groups of rules and combine them into common variables.

```
var ruleSet1 = {
        required: true,
        number: true
    };

$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: ruleSet1,
        field_2: ruleSet1,
        field_3: ruleSet1
    }
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/4/

---

**Option 2b)** Related to 2a above but depending on your level of complexity, can separate out the rules that are common to certain groups and use [`.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to recombine them in an infinite numbers of ways.

```
var ruleSet_default = {
        required: true,
        number: true
    };

var ruleSet1 = {
        max: 99
    };
$.extend(ruleSet1, ruleSet_default); // combines defaults into set 1

var ruleSet2 = {
        min: 3
    };
$.extend(ruleSet2, ruleSet_default); // combines defaults into set 2

var ruleSet3 = { };
$.extend(ruleSet3, ruleSet1, ruleSet2); // combines sets 2 & 1 into set 3.  Defaults are included since they were already combined into sets 1 & 2 previously.

$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: ruleSet2,
        field_2: ruleSet_default,
        field_3: ruleSet1,
        field_4: ruleSet3
    }
});
```

End Result:

- `field_1` will be a required number no less than 3.
- `field_2` will just be a required number.
- `field_3` will be a required number no greater than 99.
- `field_4` will be a required number between 3 and 99.

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/5/