# Looping through fields with jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use the [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin for my form validation needs but I'm unsure how to handle the case of looping through multiple fields of the same type when I can't determine their specific ID.

What I mean is I have a table which is filled with data using PHP. Each table row has a date field which are given an ID like: DODate[145100001], DODate[145100002], DODate[145100035] etc...

I can't know how many fields or which specific IDs each individual has so how can I use jQuery Validation to loop through and validate any and all DODate[x] fields?

Comment: You can use a attribute starts with selector like `$('input[id^="DODATE"]')` will select all input fields with `id` starting with `DODATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `.addClassRules()` method will create a new custom `class` that you can add to any input element for compound rule assignment.  This is a valid approach.

HOWEVER, there is another equally valid approach to solve your issue without having to add new classes, or anything else, to your HTML markup.  Use the [plugin's `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) enclosed within a jQuery `.each()` and a "starts with" jQuery selector to target all `id`'s starting with `DODate`.

```
$('input[id^="DODate"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,  // example rule
        // another rule, etc.
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rW8Zd/**

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461732/594235) for more ways to apply rules.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised I can use a class selector and [jQuery.validator.addClassRules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/)!