# Approach to validate all Textboxes using Jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have implemented validation using jquery validate plugin and trying to apply in the following ways

first added `$.validator.addMethod("character" ........);`

and executing in below ways

**1. Will apply Rules for that particular field**

```
 rules :{
        someName: {
                    character: true,
                    required: true,
                },
        }
```

**2. Will apply at class level**

```
// connect it to a css class
    $.validator.addClassRules({
        character: { character: true }
    });
```

What am looking for is is there a way i can make this validation code for all input Textboxes in a small line rather than adding class for all textboxes !

What will be the best way to implement?

As i want this validation at application level am looking for some easy approach rather touching every where!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `.addClassRules()` method will create a new custom `class` that you can add to any input element for compound rule assignment.  This is a valid approach.

HOWEVER, there is another equally valid approach to solve your issue without having to add new classes, or anything else, to your HTML markup.  Use the [plugin's `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) enclosed within a jQuery `.each()` and a jQuery selector to target all `input` elements that are `type="text"`.

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        character: true,
        required: true
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rW8Zd/1/**

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461732/594235) for more ways to apply rules.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the answer is no!

> As I want this validation at application level am looking for some
>   easy approach rather touching every where!

Since you have done validation using **`jQuery.validator.addClassRules()`**, there is an easy to add class and then approach validation.

```
$('input type["text"]').addClass('className');
```

Now the class is added to all elements of **`input type="text"`**.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks.just want to know if something like that exists