# JQuery validate - Assigning Rules as variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Am specifying rules in the below format

```
rules :{ 
col1: { 
required: true
},
col2: {
maxlength: 50
}
}
```

which completely works fine. Is it possible to assign it to the variable and add it to rules like below format

```
var testRules = "{ col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 50}}";

rules : testRules
```

The above code didnt worked am getting exception in jquery file.

if possible to do it this way. What is the correct approach or can i achieven something similar to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
var testRules = "{ col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 50}}";
```

Just get rid of the quotation marks and it will work fine.

```
var testRules = { col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 50}};
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/mNtcL/**

---

For the purposes of my example, this is the base starting code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="field_1" />
<input type="text" name="field_2" />
<input type="text" name="field_3" />
```

JS:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        field_2: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        field_3: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/

---

Yes, you can pull out the groups of rules and combine them into common variables.

```
var ruleSet1 = {
        required: true,
        number: true
    };

$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: ruleSet1,
        field_2: ruleSet1,
        field_3: ruleSet1
    }
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/4/

---

You can also use [`.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to recombine them in an infinite numbers of ways.

```
var ruleSet_default = {
        required: true,
        number: true
    };

var ruleSet1 = {
        max: 99
    };
$.extend(ruleSet1, ruleSet_default); // combines defaults into set 1

var ruleSet2 = {
        min: 3
    };
$.extend(ruleSet2, ruleSet_default); // combines defaults into set 2


$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: ruleSet2,
        field_2: ruleSet_default,
        field_3: ruleSet1
    }
});
```

End Result:

- `field_1` will be a required number no less than 3.
- `field_2` will just be a required number.
- `field_3` will be a required number no greater than 99.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/5/

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461732/594235) for more ways to apply rules.

Comment: Cant Ask for more @Sparky. Thanks for this excellent answer :)

Comment: Quick question  i have two rules
var testRules1 = { col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 10}};
var testRules2 = { col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 50}};
and in  rules how do i apply tat dynamically ? i need to apply based on conditions where i ll pass "1" or "2" and append to testRules
rules : testRules+1 //Didnt work

Comment: @Peru, the only way to dynamically change rules is with the `.rules()` method.  See `.rules('add')` to over ride and `.rules('remove')` in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, only way i can think of is by using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), like:

```
var testRules = "{ col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 50} }";
var obj=eval("("+testRules+")");
console.log( obj );
```

Comment: No need for `eval()`.  Removing the quotation marks makes it work.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/mNtcL/

Comment: @Sparky +1 for that.., yes absolutely... :),i wonder why i couldnot get that simple thing.. :(

Comment: @Sudhir Quick question  i have two rules
var testRules1 = { col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 10}};
var testRules2 = { col1: { required: true},col2: {maxlength: 50}};
and in  rules how do i apply tat dynamically ? i need to apply based on conditions where i ll pass "1" or "2" and append to testRules
rules : testRules+1 //Didnt work