# JQuery validation addClassRules combine multiple rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am mapping css classnames different rules how can I avoid repeating the addClassMethod and just use it once?

```
var cssClasses = {
        rules   : {
            required: 'validate-required',
            validateNumber: 'validate-number', 
            validateEmail: 'validate-email'
        }
    }


$.validator.addClassRules( selectors.rules.required,  {
    required: true
});

$.validator.addClassRules( selectors.rules.validateNumber,  {
    number: true,
});

$.validator.addClassRules( selectors.rules.validateEmail,  {
    email: true
});
```

Have tried to create into a single `addClassRules` method like this but this doesn't work

```
$.validator.addClassRules( selectors, {

        rules: {

            required: {
                required: true
            },
            validateNumber: {
                number: true
            },
            validateEmail: {
                email: true
            }

        }

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

> "I am mapping css classnames different rules..."

Why?  There would be no purpose in mapping each one to a class when these rules can already be assigned simply by using them as class names all by themselves.

```
<input class="required number email" ....
```

Otherwise, the *whole purpose* of `.addClassRules()` is to create a "compound" rule that can be assigned to the field using a *single custom* class.

```
<input class="myClassRule" ....
```

- there is no point in using the `.addClassRules()` method if you only want to assign ONE rule to ONE class, because each rule (the boolean rules) can already be represented as a class.
- the Object Literal is composed of `key: value` pairs representing class names with their list of rules.  The `rules` option has nothing to do with `.addClassRules()` and does not go inside this method.
- these new `addClassRules` rules are only assigned by class, these are not something you can use within the `.validate()` method.

---

**Example 1**

```
$.validator.addClassRules( "yourClass", {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    email: true
});
```

When class `yourClass` is applied to a form field, the `required`, `number`, and `email` rules will be in force.

```
<input class="yourClass" ...
```

---

**Example 2**, creates multiple different class rules at once.

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    classFoo: {
        required: true,
        number: true
    },
    classBar: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
});
```

When class `classFoo` is applied to a form field, the `required` & `number` rules will be in force.  When class `classBar` is applied to a form field, the `required` & `email` rules will be in force.

```
<input class="classFoo" ....
<input class="classBar" ....
```

---

> "tried to create into a single `addClassRules` method like this but this doesn't work"

It was constructed improperly as per above.  [Please refer to the documentation for `.addClassRules()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/).

**More ways to combine rules...**

[jQuery Validation Plugin - adding rules that apply to multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056425/594235)

[How can we specify rules for jquery validation plugin by class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9461732/594235)