# Customize min and max error messages for jQuery unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using HTML5 date type inputs with min and max attributes set.

```
<input class="AccordionLeft" data-val="true" 
id="operationDate" max="2050-01-01" min="2014-09-02" 
name="OpDate" type="date" value="">
```

When I enter a date before the min date, I get the jquery validation message from the built-in validator. I would like to customize this.
We have created several custom rules (via custom data annotations) and for our custrom validation rules, setting the error message was simple.

Is there anything like this for built-in validators?

Comment: @mplungjan - I have tried setting the HTML5 validation, but it does no change the error message. Also, if I turn off jQuery validate, I don't get the error message any more, so it looks like the error message is coming from jQuery validate and not the built-in HTML5 input validation.

Comment: Did you try looking for "jquery custom validation message" at all?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777634/jquery-validation-plugin-custom-message

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes I did, but since the rules are created by the unobtrusive validation script, I would rather not mess with it.

Comment: @mplungjan - In any case, I found a solution that works for me below, so thank you for your time.

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes, with that I agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging around a bit I found what I was looking for in the jQuery validate source code. In the full jQuery validate download there is a 'localization' folder. In this folder the default error messages are set for different languages. This is i.e. exactly what I am trying to do.

I added the following code to my custom JavaScript validations file:

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    min: 'Min some message {0}',
    max: 'Max some message {0}'
});
```

And this replaces the default messages with the ones I need. The `{0}` bit is for formating. jQuery validate replaces this with the value in the `Min` / `Max` property.