# formvalidator.net compare password not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I am using `formValidator` from **[FormValidator.net](http://formvalidator.net/#security-validators)** and I have a situation where I need to validate **password** and **compare password** fields and according to plugin this is how we it can be done.

```
<p>
  Password (at least 8 characters)
  <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min8"/>

  Confirm password
  <input name="pass" data-validation="confirmation"/>
</p>
```

and since I am using their latest version of plugin I also tried what they have suggested how to do it latest version > `2.2.1` as below:

```
<p>
      Password (at least 8 characters)
      <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min8"/>

      Confirm password
      <input name="pass" data-validation="confirmation" data-validation-confirm="pass_confirmation"/>
</p>
```

But still it is not comparing the password at all. Although I can say that minimum value comparision for `password` is happening properly. Have anyone worked on this plugin.? Is there any other way to do this?

```js
$.validate({
  form: "#frmSample",
  validateOnBlur: true, // enable validation when input looses focus
  scrollToTopOnError: true, // Set this property to true if you have a long form
  borderColorOnError: "rgb(167, 3, 0)",
  borderColorOnSuccess: "#a94442",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.43/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmSample">
 <p>
  Password (at least 8 characters)
  <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min8">
  <br/>
  Confirm password
  <input name="pass" data-validation="confirmation">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Try looking at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147438/match-two-fields-with-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: That is using different plugin @DinoMyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the security module.

Change `$.validate({options})` to `$.validate({modules:'security', options})`

In your example your code will look like:

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.43/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmSample">
 <p>
  Password (at least 8 characters)
  <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min8">
  <br/>
  Confirm password
  <input name="pass" data-validation="confirmation">
</p>
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
$.validate({
  modules : 'security',
  form: "#frmSample",
  validateOnBlur: true, // enable validation when input looses focus
  scrollToTopOnError: true, // Set this property to true if you have a long form
  borderColorOnError: "rgb(167, 3, 0)",
  borderColorOnSuccess: "#a94442",
});
```

See the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/f1jsyef7/)

---

### Update

You have to use the module 'security' because the form validator plugin is created with separate modules eg. 'location, file, swedish, uk' and you have to load the required module. If you want to use the 'uk' module you have to use `modules:'uk'` and so on.

Comment: That's awesome!! Will definitely accept this once I test in my application but before that can you please let me know why this `security` module? Any idea on this! I haven't found any description regarding this.. :)