# jQuery validation plugin, check arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-validate

I want to use "jQuery validation plugin" (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) with arrays.

I tried this solution:

[Validating array inputs using jquery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843399/validating-array-inputs-using-jquery-validation-plugin)

But it's not working for me: only one element per array is being check.

My HTML is:

```
<form id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>          
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input name="username[]" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input name="username[]" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        'username[]': "required"
    },
    messages: {
        'username[]': {
            required: "Please enter a username"
        }
    }
});
```

Here a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t14ft1ny/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-valiadte-plugin-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943121/jquery-validate-dynamic-input-array