# Validating length of array inputs using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

At first, i have searched many but no article solved my problem.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843399/validating-array-inputs-using-jquery-validation-plugin) make me know that using quote to validate array inputs.

My problem is how to validating length of array inputs. For more detail, plz read more bellow

**In my HTML:**

```
<form id="demo-form">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" id="p1">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" id="p2">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" id="p3">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" id="p4">
    <input type="submit value="submit">
</form>
```

This requires user has to enter at lease 2 products

**Script**

```
jQuery("#demo-form").validate({
    rules: {
        'product[]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2 //this only use to validate length of string inputed, not length of array products
        }
    },
});
```

How to validate length of array products?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every text input **must** have unique name in order for this plugin to operate properly.  Use `product[0]`, `product[1]`, `product[2]`, etc.
2. Use [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) to make sure at least two fields get filled out.
3. Use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) to lump the four identical error messages into one.

**Example**:

```
jQuery("#demo-form").validate({
    // other rules & options
    groups: {
        myproducts: "product[0] product[1] product[2] product[3]"
    }
});

// assign the rule to all field names that start with 'product'
jQuery('[name^="product"]').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [2, jQuery('[name^="product"]')]
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/s960pyr0/**

Comment: Seem jquery.validation not supports array input much! Btw, your solutions resolved my problem. Thanks