# validating form fields using jquery validation plugin?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validation plugin.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Today I ran into an issue where I needed to `validated fields with the same name`, something like: `<input type="text" name="foo[]" value="" />` - the problem is the plugin will only validate the first field. I know the reason is because plugin expects unique names i think. Is there any solution to validate all the fields with the same name?

Thanks!

Comment: if possible please provide a fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery Validate Plugin to validate multiple form fields with identical names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931687/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-validate-multiple-form-fields-with-identical-nam)

Comment: Why can't you give them unique names?  And no, there is no workaround.  They must be named uniquely.

Comment: have you considered using `$.each`?

Comment: There is no workaround.  Every field must have a unique name in order for this plugin to function properly.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/GuG7x/

Answer (score 0):

**Quote**:

> *"...the problem is the plugin will only validate the first field. I know the reason is because plugin expects unique names I think. Is there any solution to validate all the fields with the same name?"*

This is true.  The plugin will not operate properly without a unique name on each field.

Also, using a jQuery `$.each()` to assign rules via the `.rules('add')` method is not a viable workaround.  That's because the root problem is not with *selecting* elements & *assigning* rules, the problem is that the plugin uses the `name` attribute to *keep track* of the elements being validated.  This is impossible if the `name` is the same on all.

[failed jQuery `.each()` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GuG7x/)