# Why is this form validation with jquery not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am not being able to validate a simple HTML form using jquery. Please help. The following is my code.

Please note i am very new to jquery,so this might be a silly question to ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(){

    alert("1");

     $("#form1").validate({

     rules: { 
         name: "required", 
         age: "required", 
         id: "required", 
    },
    messages: {
        name: " Enter username", 
        age: " Enter age",
        id: " Enter id",

      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
          alert('3');
            form.submit();

      }

   });     
  }; 
  </script>
  <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2></h2>
  <form method="POST" action="addStudent.do" id=form1>
  <div id="form-content">
    <fieldset>
  <div class="fieldgroup">

      <label for="name">First Name</label> 
      <input type="text"  id="name">
  </div>

  <div class="fieldgroup">   
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text"  id="age">
  </div>   

 <div class="fieldgroup"> 
   <label for="id">Id</label>
   <input type="text" id="id">
 </div> 

    <div class="fieldgroup">

             <input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit" class="submit"    onclick="validate()">  
    </div>

   </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>


  </body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931687/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-validate-multiple-form-fields-with-identical-nam

Comment: http://www.anttivaihia.com/blog/2011/04/simple-form-validation-using-jquery

Comment: @Shivayan what validation jquery plugin have you used??

Comment: have you included jQuery library first?

Comment: yes,jquery-1.6.1.min.js & jquery.validate.min.js are the ones..

Comment: <form method="POST" action="addStudent.do" id="form1">

Comment: @shadow ,thankyou that was a mistake and i corrected it but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
       $.validator.setDefaults({
            submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

           $("#form1").validate({

            rules: { 
             name: "required", 
             age: "required", 
             id: "required", 
           },
            messages: {
            name: " Enter username", 
            age: " Enter age",
            id: " Enter id",

           }        
       });    

      }
</script>



<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
 <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit" class="submit">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys .. Finally i discovered what was wrong in it,all the fields had the "id" attribute which was not being recognized in Jquery. changing the same to "name" solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the form to

```
<form id="Form1" method="POST" action="addStudent.do">
.
.
.
```

copy and paste it and you will see it is working !